# Use RegEx to find multiple occurences of the pattern

Tags: php, regex

I got this string:

`if(conditionA==valueA-AND-conditionB==valueB-OR-conditionC==valueC)`

and I want an array that contains:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(...) "conditionA==valueA"
  [1]=>
  string(...) "conditionB==valueB"
  [2]=>
  string(...) "conditionC==valueC"
}
```

I am currently using this pattern:

```
preg_match("/^if\((.+)-(.+)\)/U", $current_step_data_exploded[0], $if_statements);
```

but it doesn't deliver the third condition properly. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -2):

```
$string = "if(conditionA==valueA-AND-conditionB==valueB-OR-conditionC==valueC)";
$match = preg_match('/^if\((.+)\)$/', $string, $if);
if ($match) {
  $conditions = preg_split('/\-(AND|OR)\-/', $if[1]);
  print_r($conditions);
} else {
  echo "no matches.";
}
```